# How to store a big integer valueintoan ArrayList of Byte

Tags: java

How can i store a int value=100,000 into a `ArrayList<Byte>`. I can't type cast because the value would change .

Is there any mechanism by which i can allocate 4 bytes in Arraylist and store the integer.

Or is it possible to with a byte[] array?

Answer (score 4):

> Or is it possible to with a byte[] array?

Yes, BigInteger have a method [`toByteArray()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/math/BigInteger.html#toByteArray%28%29)

```
byte[] resultBArray= yourBigInteger.toByteArray();
```

Even then you cannot store in `ArrayList<Byte>`, Since `Byte[]` is not `Byte`

But that seems not quite good for me, You can take a individual `List` with `Byte[]` or direct `List<BigInteger>`

```
BigInteger yourBigInteger = new BigInteger(String.valueOf(100000));
byte[] resultBArray= yourBigInteger.toByteArray();
```

to get it back

```
 int i=    new BigInteger(bytes).intValue();
```

Comment: I have a int value=100000; how can i store this one?Its not a Integer Object.

Comment: You can create an Wrapper object from primitive. Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3878192/converting-from-integer-to-biginteger

Comment: Why do i have to convert it to bigInteger?  can i jus have it as Integer?

Comment: @james Then that is cherry on cake :) `Integer intObj = new Integer(100000);`

Comment: This is not working , can you tell me what wrong here? int value=100000;Integer intObj = new Integer(value);
  byte[] resultBArray= intObj.toByteArray();//error here

Comment: @james Why you are converting it in to Integer ? Integer doesn't have a facility to give bytes.Use Big Integer.

Comment: Ok , How to get back the int value from byte[] now?I used for(int j=0;j<resultBArray.length;j++)
  {
   System.out.println(resultBArray[j]);
  }

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
BigInteger value=new BigInteger("100000");
List<byte[]> list=new   ArrayList<>();
list.add(value.toByteArray());//Put BigInteger as byte[]

BigInteger returnValue= new BigInteger(list.get(0));// Return value from list
System.out.println(returnValue);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just do

```
 byte[] byteArray = new BigInteger("100000").toByteArray();
 List<Byte> bytes = new ArrayList<>();
    for(byte b : byteArray)
        bytes.add(b);
```

Comment: Adding is OK. How can you get it back ? What if OP add two numbers ?

Comment: Why would OP add two numbers? And to get it back he could just do BigInteger big = new BigInteger(byteArray);